# What is the correct way to capture APIM request and response payload in application insights?

Tags: azure, azure-application-insights, azure-api-management

Our organization have developers from language background and each would write Function App in their own language of comfort(C#, Java or Python). All these function Apps are exposed as API in APIM. By default payloads are not captured in application insights. I have seen blogs talking about adding custom Telemetry Intializers to do this, but all at backend(i.e ASP.NET or Function app). Is there a way to add this intializer in APIM level? Or is there any other alternative way to achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here’s the doc on how to set up logging to Application Insights in APIM (including setting up headers/body logging): https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/api-management/api-management-howto-app-insights